# Web Scraping with Power Automate Web without PREMIUM components

Tags: power-automate

Is there a way to extract information from different websites via `Power Automate Web` without using any of the Add-Ins labeled as `PREMIUM`?

I have seen web scraping attempts with `Power Automate Desktop` and via the HTTP Add-In in PA Web.

But is there a way without those to get text information about newest blog posts etc.?